# What is wrong with my apache Virtual host setup?

Tags: apache

I have set up the virtual host like its displayed in the apache documentation:

NameVirtualHost Localhost:8080

```
<VirtualHost Localhost:8080>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot D:\Users\daniel_diezel\Apache24\htdocs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost Localhost:8080>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot D:\Users\daniel_diezel\Apache24\htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

After i saved it and started the httpd.exe the following error accured while starting Apache:

`

(OS 10013)Der Zugriff auf einen Socket war aufgrund der Zugriffsrechte des Sockets unzulõssig.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs`

But if i change the Port to 8080 its working.
But the problem no is when the apache starts i cant find the server when i type https://domain.ltd in my browser but if I go for Localhost:8080 it shows me the index file on the site.
What can i do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have IIS or other webserver enabled?

Comment: no  i have no other webserver enabled.

Comment: do not specify names in virtualhost tag, that's what servername is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two different issues. According to your file structure I assume you are using Windows.

### Port usage

Port 80 might be already in use. Open CMD and type `netstat -ano` and find all processes using port 80 apart from the system process (typically PID 4). Identify the processes by using the command `tasklist` and look for the PIDs using port 80 from the step before.
Now open your task manager and stop all processes if they are not relevant to keep your system running. Now the port binding error should be gone.

### Accessing local domain names

domain.tld is resolved by your configured DNS-provider, so it is looked up to be found in the internet. If you want to resolve domain-names locally (before reaching out for the DNS) you have to add it to your host file.
Open `C:/Windows/drivers/etc/hosts` with a editor of your choice an add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.tld
```

Now everything should work as expected. If you want to use different ports you can also use `127.0.0.1:port domain.tld`